# Excel VBA Macro for opening and loading information from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon folks,

I've been working on a updating some excel macros from a very old style macro setup to the VBA macros. I'm not really sure what I'm looking for as far as how to fix these, as I've only recently started learning VBA. The one I'm having the most issues with is the one that takes information from a specified workbook, plugs it into the current workbook, and doesn't override the formulas. The "HEAT5.XLSX" is the master file that will taking the information in. The original macro is this:

`

```
Open (o)
=PROTECT.DOCUMENT(FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE)
=OPEN(!F1)
=PROTECT.DOCUMENT(FALSE,FALSE,,FALSE)
=WINDOW.TITLE(!F1)
=SELECT("R1C3:R37C4")
=COPY()
=ACTIVATE("HEAT5.XLSX")
=SELECT("R1C3")
=PASTE()
=ACTIVATE(!F1)
=SELECT("R2C6:r6c6")
=COPY()
=ACTIVATE("HEAT5.XLSX")
=SELECT("R2C6")
=PASTE()
=ACTIVATE(!F1)
=SELECT("R1C14")
=COPY()
=ACTIVATE("HEAT5.XLSX")
=SELECT("R2C14")
=PASTE()
=ACTIVATE(!F1)
=PROTECT.DOCUMENT(TRUE,FALSE,,TRUE)
=CLOSE(TRUE)
=ACTIVATE("HEAT5.XLSX")
=SELECT("R1C6")
=PROTECT.DOCUMENT(TRUE,FALSE,,TRUE)
=RETURN()`
```

And what I have thus far for trying to recreate this is:

```
`Sub Retrieve()
    Dim strFName As String

    strFName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("F1").Value & ".xlsx"
    'this variable contains the workbook name and path
    If FileExists(strFName) Then
    'does it exist?
        If Not BookOpen(Dir(strFName)) Then Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFName
        'if its not already open, open it
    Else
        MsgBox "The file does not exist!"
    End If

End Sub

Function FileExists(strfullname As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir(strfullname) <> ""
End Function

Function BookOpen(strWBName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbk = Workbooks(strWBName)
    If Not wbk Is Nothing Then BookOpen = True
End Function`
```

Any recommendations and assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "doesn't override the formulas" but why don't you try this instead of what you got? Yours looks a little confusing.

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Dim wbk2 as Workbook
Set wbk as Thisworkbook 'this one will be HEAT.xlsx
Set wbk2 as Workbooks.Open("FILENAME.xlsx")

wbk2.Activate    'makes FILENAME.xlsx your active workbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,3),Cells(37,4)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

wbk.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

wbk2.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2,6),Cells(6,6).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

wbk.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

And repeat this process for the rest of your selections. Cells function works like this:

```
Cells(row number, column number)
```

Comment: So I started working at it, and I got the file to open, and it looks like it copies from the file, but then when it goes to paste into the main workbook I get an error of "Run-time error'9': Subscript out of range"

The issue comes in at ``wbk.Activate
**Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 3)).Select**
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False``

Comment: The part of the code with the `** **`around it is the problem section at the moment, just clarifying.

Comment: Sorry, you should use instead:

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Select

Comment: It appears that the issue came in that the Sheet 1 for the main workbook was somehow renamed even to VBA. I got it fixed when I changed Worksheets("Sheet1") to Worksheets("HEAT5"). Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please give up vote. Thanks!

Comment: The sheet name always feeds through to VBA. I simply put "Sheet1" because that's just the default sheet name. If you want to reference a specific sheet, you have to put in that sheet's name. Please mark the code as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I do have one more question now. I forgot that I had to have the sheets protected initially, and as such will need to be able to unprotect the sheets at the start of the code and then protect them both once again once the copying is finished. Would I just add something along the lines of: `wbk.Activate
wbk.Unprotect
wbk2.Activate
wbk2.Unprotect` 

At the start, and then `wbk.Activate
wbk.Protect
wbk2.Activate
wbk2.Protect`
At the end of the code to do this, with protection already governed on the main workbook?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "password"

[code block]


ActiveWorkbook.Protect "password", True, True

Comment: Had an issue but solved it right after posting previously...Thank you once again for all of your assistance.